# Add long click event listener on the Google Pie chart

Tags: javascript, android, charts, google-visualization, pie-chart

Is there any option to add long click event listener on the Google Pie Chart? 
For example: On long clicking on the any portion of the Google Pie chart results into starting another activity.

**Edit 1**

```
// Sets a tooltip action which will pop an alert box on the screen when triggered.
chart.setAction({
  id: 'alertAction',
  text: 'Trigger Alert',
  action: function() {
    alert('You have triggered an alert');
  }
});
```

But how can I start an other `Activity` in android using `action: function()` in android?
How can start the new activity ?

```
startActivity(new intent(OldActivity.this,NewActivity.class));
```

Comment: the PieChart supports `'click'` and `'select'` [events](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#events) -- you can also add [custom actions](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#vissetaction) to the tooltip...

Comment: @WhiteHat See the edit 1.

Comment: @WhiteHat The new activity can be started just by  `startActivity(new intent(OldActivity.this,NewActivity.class));`

Comment: @WhiteHat Cannot be. The chart code is in the JavaScript but the start activity is in Android.

Comment: try making `Context` available via `JavaScriptInterface` -- then `context.startAcitivty` within `setAction` code in javascript -- see [this question / answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809235/5090771)...